# Select() not working for me

Tags: c++, function, select

I have a problem, i use `select` function to wait when i can read received data on server side, but it works wrong like i receive nothing and timeout passed.

**Server side code:**

```
 int fd = accept(sockfd, addr, addrlen);
 if(fd > 0)
 {
     struct timeval tv;
     fd_set rfds;
     FD_ZERO(&rfds);
     FD_SET(fd, &rfds);

     tv.tv_sec = 5;
     tv.tv_usec = 0;
     // wait when i can read data
     int ret_select = select(1, &rfds, (fd_set *) 0, (fd_set *) 0, &tv);
     if(ret_select > 0)
     {
         // data ready to be readed. NEVER HERE!
     }
     else
     {
        // nothing. ALWAYS HERE
     }
    }
```

**Client side:**

```
int ret = connect(s, name, namelen);
if(ret == 0)
{
 struct timeval tv;
 fd_set rfds;
 FD_ZERO(&rfds);
 FD_SET(s, &rfds);

 tv.tv_sec = 5;
 tv.tv_usec = 0;
 // wait when we can write
 int ret_select = select(1, (fd_set *) 0, &rfds, (fd_set *) 0, &tv);
 if(ret_select > 0)
 {
  int sended = send(s, my_data, size_data, 0);
  if(sended > 0)
  {
   // all ok, data sended!
  }
 }
}
```

But if i remove on server side calling `select` - all ok, data to read is exists, so i guess `select` works wrong in my code!

Whats wrong with my code?

Thanks!

Comment: Becker, glad to see you're continuing to learn after the "Function work Timer" question yesterday! :) You might want to change the title of the question to something like: "select() not working for me"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first argument of `select()` is *not* the number of file descriptors in the set. It is:

> nfds is the highest-numbered file descriptor in any of the three sets, plus 1.

So, unless your socket file descriptor is number 0, your argument of 1 is wrong.

Comment: i know, first arguement is ignored as i know so i pasted `1`

Comment: @Becker The first argument is only ignored on Windows using winsocket. On POSIX platforms (e.g. Linux) it _must_ be set correctly.

Comment: @Becker, change the first arg from 1 to `fd+1`